# Quickest way to move numbers from one list to another

Tags: python, list, optimization, iteration

I have a list:

```
list1=[1,8,2,9,3,8,7,10]
```

I would like to know the absolute fastest way of pulling all values above say "7" and placing them into a new list. I do not want to use a for loop, that takes too long when there are hundreds of millions of items in the list.

so ideally something like this:

```
list1=[1,8,2,9,3,8,7,10]
list2=AboveNumber(7,list1)
print list2
>>>[8,9,8,10]
```

Thanks for any suggestions!
Processing times appreciated!

Comment: It could be, would that be faster?

Comment: What are you processing that makes speed a concern?  Are you sure that this list transformation is, or will be, a bottleneck?

Comment: I am processing up to hundreds of millions of numbers. Although this process is not a bottleneck, it is one of many places where a small improvement could reap substantial gains.

Comment: @fastreload Thanks! Sorting has opened up some new options and made a great increase in speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution, as cited above, is to have the list sorted and keep only the part following the interesting value. Using the ipython cell timeit

```
data = randint(10,size=2000)
```

naive method

```
%%timeit
[ i for i in data if i>7 ]
# 1.8 ms per loop
```

sorting method

```
data2 = sorted(data)
import bisect

%%timeit
data2[bisect.bisect(data2,7):]
# 13.6 us per loop
```

but in general, if you have to work on numerical data, i strongly suggest to use the **numpy** library. With the naive method is already almost as fast as the sorting method

```
import numpy as np
adata = np.array(data)

%%timeit
adata[adata>7]
# 28.5 us per loop
```

but you can use the sorting method even with the numpy array:

```
adata.sort()

%%timeit
adata[adata.searchsorted(7):]
# 2.1 us per loop
```

The bigger the array, greater the performance of the numpy array, which is close to an optimized C routine (actually, they are a bunch of optimized C code, you just pay the overload of calling the python wrapper)

#### EDIT:

note that the relationship between speed varies with the array size. the naive numpy method and the sorting method of the list are at the same speed for roughly 5*10^5 elements, while at the same size the numpy method with the sorted array is more or less 3000 time faster.

Comment: Thank you for the times! That gives me an excellent idea of how much quicker the various approaches are :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about maintaining a sorted order and use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(50)
print a[a >= 7]

#[ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
```

If you have items that are sorted already you can make use of the `bisect` module (or `numpy` has its own methods for working with sorted data):

```
import bisect

items = range(50)
index = bisect.bisect_left(items, 7)
print items[index:]
# [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
```

And to add items in sorted order:

```
bisect.insort_left(items, 3)
print items
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, .. snip ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

AboveNumber can do no magic. If the list is unordered, it must run through all items in the list.

You can optimize this by maintaining the list in order, i.e. by making sure that the list is always ordered after an insert or erase.

If the list is ordered, you may find your "mean" by a binary search, which would be much faster than running through all the list, then cut the list at that position.

Comment: @Dlinet Can numbers repeat?

Comment: @Dlinet `list2 = list1[index:]`, a slice is the easiest way. But that copies the part of the list, so it's again O(n). Since lists are mutable, you can't easily avoid copying (you can do it like Java's `String` class and share the same underlying list (array) for slices and only copy on mutation, but that's not entirely uncomplicated). Depending on what you need, maybe using a balanced binary search tree could be more efficient for you.

Comment: As thank you! I investigated and learned that you can slice the original list. That way no copying is needed Ex: list=list[0:5]